# What research exists on Speech to LaTeX / MathML?

Tags: conversion, accessibility, research

## Preface

I'm currently working in the area of speech recognition and simultaneous lecture translation. Essentially, you have one speaker (the lecturer) who speaks in German (for example) and many students who don't understand German. The speaker can get the spoken translation of their words, in any language they like, just a few seconds after they speak.

So the process involves:

1. Transforming German speech into German text; and
2. Transforming German text into text in a foreign language; and
3. Synthesizing speech for text in a foreign language.

This system has already been built and works amazingly well—it's far from perfect, but works well enough for you to be able to get an idea what the lecture is about.

An example for this system is right at the beginning of this video:

[Video: Simultaneous machine translation (in German)](http://youtu.be/x5lL0wpr-88)

But where the system currently really sucks is math. For example, when you say something like:

```
The sum from n equals 1 to infinity of 1 over n squared goes to infinity.
```

It will recognize exactly this. But I think it should recognize

```
$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2} \rightarrow \infty$
```

or something similar. And yes, I am aware of the fact that even humans cannot always tell how speech (especially without context) would translate to LaTeX without any ambiguity. But even providing several alternatives would be a big improvement.

## My Question

Are there any papers that deal with the problem "math speech to text" or "math speech to (La)TeX" or "math speech to MathML"?

I have seen a question asking about [LaTeX to MathML to speech](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/37640/5645) but not the other way round.

I've also found [metroplexvoice.com](http://metroplexvoice.com/), but this is not natural language. They make unnaturally long pauses for the system, and they say things like "newline".

## Summary of papers I know

When people who are interested in the same topic read this question, they should not have to read the whole paper to get a rough idea what it is about. So I'll try to summarize the ones I've read

### [How can we speak math?](http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~fateman/papers/speakmath.pdf)

The first part of this paper is about text to speech (or rather math to speech). It explains ambiguity of math speech and recommends a multimodal approach (speech and text) for on-line recognition of math.

Answer (score 6):

You are taking on a REALLY hard problem that is IMHO not solvable in your context. When humans speak math, they frequently speak it ambiguously. A simple example is "b plus c over d". Even if you get 100% recognition of the tokens of the language, which is a challenge with single letter tokens, there is no way to know if this is \frac{b+c}{d} or b+\frac{c}{d}.

When computers speak math for people who are blind, they need to add somewhat unnatural delimiters in such as "fraction ... over ... end fraction" to make the speech unambiguous. Fateman's paper discusses this need and suggests one way of speaking 2D expressions. Because you probably don't want to force your speakers to speak a certain way, I suspect translating the words and leaving the listener to piece together the expression in their mind is better than trying to create the math notation in TeX or MathML and being wrong a non-trivial amount of time.

In addition to ambiguous speech, another big challenge that you will face is that there are many, many ways to speak the same notation. Some are simple variants ("loop integral" and "countour integral"). However, others have many variations and are inconsistently used even by a single speaker. As an example, someone might speak a parenthesized quantity with a pause and rate change one time, say "quantity" or "all" or some other phrase another time, or might even speak the parens (open/close) in one of several ways yet another time.

If you are willing to train your speakers to speak math in some specified way to eliminate the ambiguity and simplify the number of variations you need to deal with, then I think the problem is solvable. But even with those simplifications, it is still a really hard problem because you are going to need to drive down recognition problems with some clever context recognition that likely requires a large body of sample equations.

Comment: Well, I know that arbitrary math speech is very ambiguos. But math speech of lectures that you know, where you collect data from the past years, where you know the domain of a lecture and might be able to access scripts, is not that hard. It is still ambiguous, but I think it is work a try. (And: No, speakers should just speak math as they did before.)

Answer (score 5):

This paper from 2012, ["Application of Fuzzy Mathematics to Speech-to-Text Conversion by Elimination of Paralinguistic Content"](http://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1209/1209.4535.pdf), may be helpful.

The abstract states:

> For the past few decades, [people have] been trying to create an intelligent
>   computer which can talk and respond like he can. The task of creating
>   a system that can talk like a human being is the primary objective of
>   Automatic Speech Recognition. Various Speech Recognition techniques
>   have been developed in theory and have been applied in practice. This
>   paper discusses the problems that have been encountered in developing
>   Speech Recognition, the techniques that have been applied to automate
>   the task, and a representation of the core problems of present day
>   Speech Recognition by using Fuzzy Mathematics. (Lakra et al. 1)

---

References:

Lakra, Sachin et al. “Application of Fuzzy Mathematics to Speech-to-Text Conversion by Elimination of Paralinguistic Content.” *arXiv:1209.4535 [cs]* (2012): n. pag. arXiv.org. Web. 9 Jan. 2014.

Comment: ***Man** has been trying to create an intelligent computer*... as opposed to ***women***, who where conspicuously uninterested in any such scientific endeavour?

Comment: Had I been the editor of the paper I quoted, I would have corrected their faux pas.

Comment: @PhilVollman: Thanks for the paper (+1) and the many edits to my question. When you improve my texts you also help me to improve my English :-)

Comment: @moose Well, when I read "man", I surely find it hard to imagine a human being with breasts. I try to avoid using *man* in that fashion as much as possible.

Comment: @moose If you closely stick to the English text, I guess you would have translate this occurence of "man" as "Mensch", which if I remember my German from high-school, doesn't sound half as sexist as "man". Anyway, this debate belongs somewhere else...

Comment: @Jubobs 'Mensch' sounds affable, I'd say. "You're a real mensch, ya know?" etc...

Comment: @PhilVollman I meant "Mensch" as used in German, not in English...

Comment: @PhilVollman: I've just realized that your answer doesn't quite fit to my question. I was asking about special content that should get recognized (mathematical formulae), but the paper you've mentioned about a special type of mathematics (fuzzy math) being applied to recognize speech.

Answer (score 1):

You are saying "I think it should recognize the text with formulae"…. I challenge that.

The language of a teacher describing the mathematics being written on the blackboard is not about reading aloud a formula. This would be horribly boring.

There's a few studies that say that teaching math is boosted by waving hands, and indeed all normal math lecturers do wave hands when they write (see [here](http://www.newscientist.com/article/dn8742-hand-waving-boosts-mathematics-learning.html) for example).

Similarly, no lecturer that i know of actually reads only the text he writes on the blackboard…

Thus, I would suggest that you limit yourself to the translation of the words but make an effort so that the presentation is synchronized with the translation. Even including the video in the live translation would help I think.