# Accessible TeX/LaTeX textbooks, primers, and materials?

Tags: big-list, accessibility

I apologize, as this is a somewhat off-the-beaten-trail question.

I'm looking for textbooks (or other educational materials) on TeX and LaTeX that fulfill one or more of the following:

- Reads/renders well with a screen reader (namely [TextHelps's Read & Write Gold](http://www.texthelp.com/uk/our-products/readwrite));
- is typeset (or can be re-typeset) with a LD-friendly font such as [OpenDyslexic](http://opendyslexic.org/);
- comes with online materials in the vein of [MyMathLab](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MyMathLab) or MyCommunicationLab (viz. flashcards and quizzes);
- has an audiobook version (MP3 or [DTB](http://www.daisy.org/daisypedia/daisy-digital-talking-book)); and/or
- is available via [BookShare](http://www.bookshare.org).

I hope this question isn't too off-topic, because I have been having a genuinely hard time finding a textbook or primer that meets my needs.

---

P.S: Are there any TeX/LaTeX tutors in the Washington, D.C. area? 1:1 instruction is how I learn best, to be frank.

P.P.S: Are there any good flashcard sets for memorizing LaTeX snippets, macros, and commands?

Comment: Re: flashcards: I guess *using* LaTeX is a better idea - you memorize what you need.  Re: other requirements/accessibility: what about using Org-mode instead with Emacspeak?  (I don't know that solution, just an idea to see whether it makes any sense.)

Comment: I don't know how accessible these are, but I have HTML versions of my LaTeX textbooks [LaTeX for Complete Novices](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/novices/html/) and [Using LaTeX to Write a PhD Thesis](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/thesis/html/). Since they're HTML you can use your browser to switch off the CSS and set the font according to your preferences. Most of the images either have a brief description in the `alt` tag or they link to a page describing the image.

Comment: @NicolaTalbot  Your books seem like a great starting point--thanks! You can add your comment as an answer, if you'd like to do so.

Comment: i disagree that the question [What is the best book to start learning LaTeX?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/11/579) is a duplicate, although the answers given there are excellent and comprehensive -- for what was asked -- and there's a further link to non-english resources.  however, *this* question is about materials that are **accessible**, i.e., can be read *aloud*, have the source available so they can be reset in special fonts readable by the visually challenged, and similar requirements.

Comment: along these same lines is the question [Are there good resources for converting TeX type files to spoken word?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/37640/579).  the thesis by T.V.Raman, "AsTeR -- Audio System For Technical Readings" is backed up by a number of audio files, linked from [an html top-level summary](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/home/raman/aster/aster-toplevel.html).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

(Converting my comment into an answer.)

My [series of LaTeX books](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/) are provided as paperback, PDF (free) and HTML (free). The HTML versions were specifically designed to be accessible, although I don't have all the accessibility software installed to test it. With the HTML versions, you can use your browser to switch off the CSS and set the font to a size or style that's easier to read. Most of the images showing the typeset output from the examples either have a brief description in the `alt` tag or link to a page with a longer description and the nearest HTML approximation.

The first two volumes are: [LaTeX for Complete Novices](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/novices/html/) and [Using LaTeX to Write a PhD Thesis](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/thesis/html/). The third volume (which covers more advanced topics) isn't finished yet, but it will follow the same format as the other two.