# Quickly writing LaTeX documents

Tags: learning, accessibility

I am hoping someone can give me some help.  I am very new to using latex, but I am taking a class that requires some advanced mathematical equations and also drawing of various types of tree diagrams.

I have succeeded in creating my first document with the equations and tree diagrams but it took me forever to write the necessary latex code to do it.

I am concerned because within about three weeks, I will have a timed test where I will have to do similar types of equations and tree graphs.

Is there a "quick" way to create latex documents?

BTW: I am blind, and all of the latex editors I have tried so far are not accessible.  I am willing to try other editors though.

Any tips would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Related: [Accessible TeX/LaTeX textbooks, primers, and materials?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/168528/5764)

Comment: Related: [What are good learning resources for a LaTeX beginner?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/11/5764)

Comment: the author of tex4ht, eitan gurari (sadly passed in 2009) was interested in latex for blind people - don't know though whether it ever came to anything ...

Comment: There was a thread on [comp.text.tex](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/comp.text.tex/blind|sort:relevance/comp.text.tex/TjQJMdhFqH4/AMzTFPWXO6oJ) back in 2007 on a similar topic -- the main difference being the OP was a CS student. Eitan Gurari was also involved in the thread. Not sure if it's much help, however....

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Are there special editors for blind people? Which one do you use?

Comment: You could try out markdown with [pandoc](http://pandoc.org), that way you only have to use LaTeX-code for diagrams and math, while you can use the far easier markdown syntax for sectioning and lists and the like.

Comment: This TeX.SX link might be helpful: [teaching latex to visually disabled](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47054/teaching-latex-to-visually-disabled).

Comment: Are all students required to use LaTeX? Definitely if not, and possibly even if they are, you should raise the issue with your instructor and/or an advisor on your campus who deals with accommodations for students with disabilities. You should do this as soon as possible, even if you hope that you will find a good solution before the timed test.

Comment: I'm guessing from your phrasing that you are totally blind. Is that correct? [I'm legally blind, but can see well enough to use text editors with very large font.]

Comment: There is a series of posts at [blind science](http://www.blindscience.org/blindmath-gems-latex) that may be useful. One mentions using Emacs and [Emac Speak](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EmacSpeak).

Answer (score 1):

You could try editors like [Texmaker](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Texmaker) or [TeXstudio](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TeXstudio) There is a "Wizard" in the panel - when you press it, you could choose "Assistent for a new document" or something like that. It is an easy way to create a document - and it has all the AMS packages you need, and the geometry package. You just have to choose what you want, by pressing some buttons. Here a [comparison of TeX editors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_TeX_editors).

Else you can easily [google some LaTeX templates](http://lmgtfy.com/?q=latex%20templates). Actually, [this is really good page](http://www.latextemplates.com/) with a lot of templates.

But, of course, you have to edit the templates or the Quick-Starter document to what you want and what you need. But that is a way to start a LaTeX document quickly.

Yours faithfully, hoped I could help a little bit?

PS! Often you just need to make one (or a few) templates on your own (by editing templates or creating it from new). And than just copy your own template every time you want to make a new LaTeX document - that works for me, but  of course sometimes I need to add some usepackages.

PPS! [Here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/68821/is-it-possible-to-create-a-latex-preamble-header) is explained how you can include the preamble with a single line to a new document.

Comment: Templates are dangerous. Abeginner cannot judge if a template is up to date or just some rubbish an idiot put together and labeled *template*. Sadly, the last mentioned get the most advertisement.