# how to programmatically convert mathml or LaTeX formulas in spoken words?

Tags: conversion, accessibility, convert, mathml

I've a formula, eg:

[image]

where the latex's code is:

```
\int_{a}^{b} \frac{1}{\sqrt{\rho}} d\rho
```

The output should be somthing like this:
"The integral from a to b of one over the square root of ro in de ro."

I'm aware of [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/37640/are-there-good-resources-for-converting-tex-type-files-to-spoken-word), but I'm interested in a tool/library/service used by a un*x program "headless" and more the answer is ten years old, I  hope something new is available.

Comment: currently mathjax speech rules are probably the most advanced thing here, you could access them via a headless browser but see https://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/basic/a11y-extensions.html#a11y-extensions

Comment: or more directly to the underlying speech rule engine https://speechruleengine.org/

Comment: @DavidCarlisle if you answer I can give you the "correct" :)

Comment: See: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/454944/is-there-screen-reader-software-or-a-built-in-method-that-supports-latex-equat Also this: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/352649/can-we-get-maths-in-pdfs-that-can-be-copy-pasted-and-screen-read

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently mathjax speech rules are probably the most advanced thing here, you could access them via a headless browser but see

https://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/basic/a11y-extensions.html

Or more directly to the underlying speech rule engine

https://speechruleengine.org

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [MathCAT](https://nsoiffer.github.io/MathCAT/), a Rust library for converting MathML to speech strings.

Demo: https://nsoiffer.github.io/MathCATDemo/

Answer (score 1):

For completeness of the solution list, following the [David Carlisle](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/1090/david-carlisle) suggestion, I've develop a MathJax wrapper:

[latex-to-speak-http-gateway](https://github.com/bicf/latex-to-speak-http-gateway)